# string+ select query order by + string ;

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want output as get all tables from a database with name as 'T_'.
I have written the query ,it gets all the table name.
but I want no get the query as 'select count(*) from all tables in database union'

means I want to get

```
select count(*) from T1 UNION
select count(*) from T2 UNION
select count(*) from T3 UNION...
```

and so on
there are 1000 of rows so I want a query which will output the count(*) query itself.

```
select 'select count(*) from ' + table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_type='BASE TABLE' 
and left(table_name,2) = 'T_'
order by TABLE_NAME
```

this query gives all `select count(*) table names like T_*`

```
select 'select count(*) from ' + table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_type='BASE TABLE' 
and left(table_name,2) = 'T_'
order by TABLE_NAME
+'UNION';
```

Getting output

```
select count(*) from T_T1
select count(*) from T_T2
select count(*) from T_T3
```

expected output

```
select count(*) from T_T1 UNION
select count(*) from T_T2 UNION
select count(*) from T_T3 UNION
```

Answer (score 2):

`order by TABLE_NAME + ' UNION'` means you want want to order by the value of `TABLE_NAME` with the sting `UNION` concatenated onto it (which will change nothing)

You need to put the `UNION` (I actually suggest `UNION ALL` here) in  your `SELECT`: `...table_type='BASE TABLE' + N' UNION ALL '`.

I also suggest changing `table_name` to `QUOTENAME(table_name)`. Giving you a final query of:

```
SELECT N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) +  NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND LEFT(TABLE_NAME, 2) = 'T_'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'select count(*) from ' + table_name + ' UNION ' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA ...
```

Comment: Take the time to explain your answer here @User3070308. code only answers  often don't help the OP learn why your solution works. Thanks! :)

Comment: the reason why your script doesn't work is because you put `+ 'UNION'` outside the script , so the `UNION` not printed